# Tcolorboxed table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox

In this Manual for tcolorbox [Manual for tcolorbox](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) how did the author(s) created the table of contents with tcolorbox?

Thank you very much.

Comment: He insert `\listofcontents` in breakable `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Ok thanks... For example `\tcolorbox{tableofcontents}`. Could I define a complex `tcolorbox` or a `newtcbox` or `newtcolorbox` in whose I insert `tableofcontents`?

Comment: Of course.  tcolorbox` manual has many examples how to design (breakable) boxes. Just try! Learning by doing is the best way to learn something ...

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Comment: The exact source lines producing the toc of manual of tcolorbox are [here](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/e25e8f51ff49417ff96d0435f7bbd9483f321dfe/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.doc.abstract.tex#L96-L117).

Comment: @muzimushi And what is that?